# How to get a bool value (true) if the user's default theme is dark on flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to change colors manually in the code when the default theme config is dark.

Does anyone know how can I get a boolean value (true) when the deafult system theme of the user is dark on flutter?

I've spent a lot of time searching in google and pub.dev but I haven't found similar problems.

Here is a example

```
backgroundColor: _isthemedark ? Colors.blue : Colors.red
```

here is my code full code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';




void main() {

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));///status bar transparent
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {


  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool _isObscure = true;

  final bool _isthemedark = true;/// HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(

     /// color: HexColor("#fafafa"),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: _isthemedark ? HexColor("#2b2e4a") : HexColor("#fafafa"),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 20),
                      child: Text('Opa!',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  color: _isthemedark ? Colors.white : HexColor("#2b2e4a") ,),),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),///texto

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 20,
                ),///blankspace

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    cursorColor: _isthemedark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: _isthemedark? Colors.white : HexColor("#666a7b").withOpacity(0.7))),
                        labelText: 'Username',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
                  ),
                ),///Username field

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),///blankspace

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: _isObscure,
                    cursorColor: _isthemedark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          color: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                          icon: Icon(_isObscure
                              ? Icons.visibility_off
                              : Icons.visibility,
                              color: _isObscure ? HexColor("#fafafa"):HexColor("#05c46b")),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: _isthemedark ? Colors.white : HexColor("#666a7b").withOpacity(0.7))),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
                  ),
                ),///password field

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),///blank space

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: TextButton(
                          style:TextButton.styleFrom(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              primary: HexColor("#666a7b")
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Opa senha?')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),///tanso?

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 450,
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: const Text ('LOGIN'),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        shadowColor: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                        elevation: 20,
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),///LOGIN button

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),///blank space

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: TextButton(
                      style:TextButton.styleFrom(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          primary: HexColor("#666a7b")
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Criar Conta')),
                )///criar acc

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}///Login page
```

**Updated code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));

  ///status bar transparent
  runApp(const LoginPage());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  late String theme;
  var brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.platformBrightness;
  bool _isObscure = true;
  late bool _isThemeDark;


  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      theme = Brightness.dark.toString();
      _isThemeDark = true;
    } else {
      theme = Brightness.light.toString();
      _isThemeDark = false;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      theme = Brightness.dark.toString();
      _isThemeDark = true;
    } else {
      theme = Brightness.light.toString();
      _isThemeDark = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///############## If I put the code above, it crashes (Red Screen)
    ///final dark = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    ///##############
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      /// color: HexColor("#fafafa"),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: _isThemeDark ? HexColor("#2b2e4a") : HexColor("#fafafa"),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        'Opa!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          color:
                          _isThemeDark ? Colors.white : HexColor("#2b2e4a"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),///texto


                const SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 20,
                ),


                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    cursorColor: _isThemeDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: _isThemeDark
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.black)),
                        labelText: 'Username',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
                  ),
                ),///Username field


                const SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),///blankspace


                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: _isObscure,
                    cursorColor: _isThemeDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          color: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                          icon: Icon(
                              _isObscure
                                  ? Icons.visibility_off
                                  : Icons.visibility,
                              color: _isObscure
                                  ? HexColor("#fafafa")
                                  : HexColor("#05c46b")),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: _isThemeDark
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.black)),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
                  ),
                ),///password field


                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),///blank space


                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: TextButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              primary: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text('Opa senha?')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),///tanso?


                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 450,
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: const Text('LOGIN'),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        shadowColor: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                        elevation: 20,
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),///LOGIN button


                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),///blank space


                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          primary: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Criar Conta')),
                )///criar acc


              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MediaQuery` widget to check whether the platform brightness is dark:

```
final dark = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
```

Put the above line of code inside `build` method, so when the user changes the system setting, your app will be automatically rebuilt.

---

Full example as requested, modified from the default flutter counter project, only 2 lines of change:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ New line below:
    final dark = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    /// @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ New line above.

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),

            /// @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ New line below:
            Text(dark ? 'Dark Mode' : 'Light Mode'),
            /// @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ New line above.
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Adding one line to your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));

  ///status bar transparent
  runApp(const LoginPage());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late String theme;
  var brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.platformBrightness;
  bool _isObscure = true;
  late bool _isThemeDark;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      theme = Brightness.dark.toString();
      _isThemeDark = true;
    } else {
      theme = Brightness.light.toString();
      _isThemeDark = false;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      theme = Brightness.dark.toString();
      _isThemeDark = true;
    } else {
      theme = Brightness.light.toString();
      _isThemeDark = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///#####################################################################
    final dark = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    ///#####################################################################
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Login Page')),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('dark: $dark'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I put these code inside `Widget build(BuildContext context)`  it says: `No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets`

Comment: @VictorSchramm Make sure the `build` method of the widget you are doing this, has a `MaterialApp` as the ancenstor, i.e. don't make this code "too high" in the widget tree. Put it at a place where you need to actually render the different UI based on brightness.

Comment: Hmmm, but where is the `build` method on my code? I'm only able to put this code above  `Widget build(BuildContext context) {` otherwise it display errors on Android Studio... All my widgets are inside a `MaterialApp` as you can see here: `Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return MaterialApp(

      color: HexColor("#fafafa"),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,

      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(...) );

  }`  Sorry if my question is stupid, I'm kinda new to flutter...

Comment: @VictorSchramm Oh I see, in your code, you put everything into a single widget, that's not a good practice. Find your `Scaffold` widget, break that (and everything below it) into a new widget, just like "class MyHomePage" in the original "flutter counter" example (automatically created when you made a new flutter project).

Comment: Hmmmm, thanks for the advice. I tried to break the Scaffold and making a Stateless widget but got the red screen error: `no MediaQuery widget ancestror found.`  Can you please demonstrate how you would do it using my code, please?

Comment: @VictorSchramm I've attached a full example, the default project with only 2 lines modified, look out for "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" in the code to see where the changes are.

Comment: I've done the changes in my code but still getting the red screen error. I've updated my code with the `Scaffold` break as you demonstrated  but if I add the lines with `############` the red screen shows up. Do you know what I've done wrong?

Comment: @VictorSchramm I tried your updated code, it works fine. Must be something else wrong within your `Scaffold` body, unrelated to this question. Try removing everything inside your scaffold (to help identify the problem), or check out my copy of your updated code, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to changes using

```
void didChangePlatformBrightness()
```

https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangePlatformBrightness.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));

  ///status bar transparent
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  
  late String theme;
  var brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.platformBrightness;
  bool _isObscure = true;
  late bool _isThemeDark;

  /// HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      theme = Brightness.dark.toString();
      _isThemeDark = true;
    } else {
      theme = Brightness.light.toString();
      _isThemeDark = false;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      theme = Brightness.dark.toString();
      _isThemeDark = true;
    } else {
      theme = Brightness.light.toString();
      _isThemeDark = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("CHECK CONSOLE");
    print(theme);
    print(_isThemeDark);
    return MaterialApp(
      /// color: HexColor("#fafafa"),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: _isThemeDark ? HexColor("#2b2e4a") : HexColor("#fafafa"),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        'Opa!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          color:
                              _isThemeDark ? Colors.white : HexColor("#2b2e4a"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                ///texto
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 20,
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    cursorColor: _isThemeDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: _isThemeDark
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : HexColor("#666a7b").withOpacity(0.7))),
                        labelText: 'Username',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
                  ),
                ),

                ///Username field

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),

                ///blankspace

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: _isObscure,
                    cursorColor: _isThemeDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          color: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                          icon: Icon(
                              _isObscure
                                  ? Icons.visibility_off
                                  : Icons.visibility,
                              color: _isObscure
                                  ? HexColor("#fafafa")
                                  : HexColor("#05c46b")),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: _isThemeDark
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : HexColor("#666a7b").withOpacity(0.7))),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
                  ),
                ),

                ///password field

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),

                ///blank space

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: TextButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              primary: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text('Opa senha?')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                ///tanso?

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 450,
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: const Text('LOGIN'),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        shadowColor: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                        elevation: 20,
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: HexColor("#05c46b"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                ///LOGIN button

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),

                ///blank space

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          primary: HexColor("#666a7b")),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Criar Conta')),
                )

                ///criar acc
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full code example? or can you apply these changes on my code above?